# Using IFrame in the Webpage

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe

I am developing an eCommerce Application using PHP/MySQL. I am using a Template(vlibtemplate) for the design.

I notice that, I am not able to insert iframes in the template pages. The template page where iframe is inserted is not rendered at all.

Can you please advise me, how to enable iframes ? I checked the header file as well, I dont block any iframe there :

This is how my header file looks :

```
 <meta name="description" content="{var name='description'}" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="{var name='keywords'}" />
        <meta name="author" content="{var name='author_name'} />
    <!--Mobile Specific Meta Tag-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

Comment: your template engine is filtering the iframes, find the config to allow iframes